# VBS: Permission denied when deleting a file or a folder

Tags: vbscript

This is my code, which first checks for a folder which contains the installer, if found, runs the uninstall and deletes the uninstall.exe if it still exists. Lastly, it deletes the folder itself.

```
Dim objFSO
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set wshshell = wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
If objFSO.FolderExists("C:\Installer_3_00_00") Then 
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Installer_3_00_00")
    if objFSO.FileExists("C:\Installer_3_00_00\uninstall.exe") Then
        Wshshell.run "C:\Installer_3_00_00\uninstall.exe -q"
    End if
    if objFSO.FileExists("C:\Installer_3_00_00\uninstall.exe") Then
        Set objFile=objFSO.GetFile("C:\Installer_3_00_00\uninstall.exe")
        objFile.Delete True
    End if
objFolder.Delete True
Else
End If 
Set objFSO = Nothing
```

The problem is: It says Permission denied trying to delete a file or folder. I cross checked by deleting manually and it worked. I have searched for similar problems in this forum but none of which helped me to solve this particular issue.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks

P.s I tried formatting my code here, but still I was not able to format it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is most likely caused by the (un)installer still running when you try to delete it, because this call:

```
Wshshell.run "C:\Installer_3_00_00\uninstall.exe -q"
```

returns immediately without waiting for the program to finish. Change that line into this:

```
Wshshell.Run "C:\Installer_3_00_00\uninstall.exe -q", 0, True
```

Comment: ya...Thanks again.. I just figured it out...I added sleep of 8 seconds and it worked.....but rather than my sleep, i will use ur statement..Thanks again for helping me out..